# Get TypeError: $(...)[0] is undefined

Tags: jquery, undefined, typeerror

My code calls an ajax script when a button is clicked. The ajax script is just returning a 0 or 1 at this point like this:

```
    $result = 1;
    echo json_encode($result);
```

The problem is with this line:

```
    $('.adt-checkbox_0')[0].prop("checked", result);
```

It gives the error

> TypeError: $(...)[0] is undefined; can't access its "prop" property

The code seems to work but it looks like it runs twice since I get failures occasionally (error messages in the php code). If I remove the [0], as I've seen in some posts, the error goes away but the script doesn't work. I added the code below in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/aevp230d/) but it doesn't work, I guess, due to the php function. Can someone explain what is wrong with that statement? Should I have a line checking if it exists? If so, how do I do that?

```
    <form>
    <tr> 
    <input type="hidden" name="pid-adt-checkbox_0" value="14" id="pid-adt-checkbox_0" /> 
    <td class="adt" id="adt-checkbox_0"><input type="checkbox" name="adt_check_0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
    <input type="hidden" name="pid-adt-checkbox_1" value="15" id="pid-adt-checkbox_0" /> 
    <td class="adt" id="adt-checkbox_1"><input type="checkbox" name="adt_check_1" /></td>
    </tr>
    </form>


    <script>
    $(".adt").click(function(){

        var next_id = $(this).closest('td').attr('id') ;
        var pid_id = 'pid-'+next_id;
        var pid = $("#"+pid_id).val();  

        var dataArray = {};
        dataArray[0] = 'change_status';
        dataArray[1] = 'oID';
        dataArray[2] = pid;  

        $.ajax({
           type:  'POST',
           data:  dataArray ,
           async: false,
           url:"adt_ajax.php",
           dataType: 'json',
           success:function(result) {
             $('.adt-checkbox_0')[0].prop("checked", result);
           }
        });
        return false;      

    }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Even if you found the element, what you are doing doesn't make sense.  `prop()` is a jQuery method, not a native Element method.  So doing `[0]` to break the Element out of the jQuery object doesn't make sense.

Comment: You cannot check a hidden field - also your HTML is invalid

Comment: You shouldn’t need the `[0]` - most jQuery functions will work as you’d hope on a multiple selection

Comment: Did you mean `$("[name=adt_check_0]").prop("checked",result=="true")`

Comment: `$('.adt-checkbox_0')` doesn't exist. you meant `#` closetypo

Comment: Taplar - I got the code I used from this page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery I have multiple checkboxes and only want to change one at a time. Is the example on that page incorrect?

Comment: MTCoster - I tried it without the [0]. the error didn't display but the code didn't work. mplungjan - I tried that code and it did the same as removing the [0] - no error but didn't work.  Kevin B - .adt-checkbox_0 is the id of one of the boxes so it does exist.

Comment: In that case you want to use `eq(0)` to keep it as a jQuery object that has access to the `prop()` method

Comment: I'm not familiar with that command so I may not have added it correctly, but I used this: $('.adt-checkbox_0').eq[0].prop("checked", result); and the error is now TypeError: $(...).eq[0] is undefined; can't access its "prop" property

Answer (score 0):

The problems:

- `adt-checkbox_0` is not `class` but `id`, the fix change it to `#adt-checkbox_0`
- `adt-checkbox_0` is not `input[type=checkbox]` but `td` the fix: `#adt-checkbox_0 input`
- using index `[0]` will return native JS object not jQuery, the fix: use `.eq(0)`

Solution if want to use the `[0]`

```
$('#adt-checkbox_0 input')[0].checked = result
```

using jQuery

```
$('#adt-checkbox_0 input').eq(0).prop("checked", result);
```